# Find amount of updated rows in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to find the amount of updated rows

```
UPDATE Table SET value=2 WHERE value2=1

declare @aaa int
set @aaa = @@ROWCOUNT
```

It doesn't work. How can I do that?

Comment: Your code works. What error message do you get ?  If you need to display it, just SELECT @aaa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You may want to declare before you do the update. I am not sure but declare statement might affect @@rowcount.
2. You are not getting the @aaa value back - you want to `select` it out if you want to see it outside the query

.

```
declare @aaa int -- this name's noty the best... use @row_count instead ;)
UPDATE Table SET value=2 WHERE value2=1
set @aaa = @@ROWCOUNT
select @aaa
```

Comment: Thanks! That works. I also found out that I can use CAST function.

Comment: @Alex - you're welcome. You might want to accept the answer if it was helpful - that's the big checkmark to the left of the answer :)

Comment: I always do  :) The thing is it asked me to wait for 8 minutes, and I forgot to, sorry. Accepted now.